# como poner scrollTop en Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buen día, he echo una pagina web: [spotcloud.io](http://spotcloud.io) pero cuando lo tengo en móvil y yo estoy ya sea en medio o abajo de la pagina y entro al menú e ingreso a otra pagina esta me sale en donde yo estaba de la anterior pagina

Un ejemplo yo estoy al final de la pagina de home y abro el menú y entro a otra pagina en esta nueva pagina sale abajo y no sale en el inicio de la pagina, entonces quería saber como hacer un scrollTop

para el menu yo ocupo HashRouter

en mi index.js

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router basename="/" hashType="noslash">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/technologies" component={Technologies} />
          <Route path="/usecases" component={UseCases} />
          <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
          <Route path="/contactus" component={ContactUs} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

y este seria el el nav:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
const menuitems = [
  <div className="div_1">
    <a href="/">HOME</a>
  </div>,
  <div className="div_1">
    <a href="/#technologies">TECHNOLOGIES</a>
  </div>,
  <div className="div_1">
    <a href="/#usecases">USE CASES</a>
  </div>,
  <div className="div_1">
    <a href="/#aboutus">About us</a>
  </div>,
  <div className="div_1">
    <a href="/#contactus">CONTACT US</a>
  </div>
];
const Nav = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const { pathname } = props.location;
  const newItems = menuitems.map(item => {
    let { props } = item;
    let { className } = props;
    const addClass =
      item.props.children.props.href
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(pathname.toLowerCase(), "") === "";
    className = `${className} ${addClass && "active"}`;
    return React.cloneElement(item, {
      ...props,
      className
    });
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div className="nav">
        <a className="vision" href="/">
          <img src={require("../../assets/img/SPOT.png")} />
        </a>
        <div className="nav_2">
          <div className="menu">
            {newItems}
            <div className={`burger_ ${open}`} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
              <div className="bar_" />
              <div className="bar_" />
              <div className="bar_" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {open && <main className="menu_responsive">{newItems}</main>}
    </>
  );
};
export default withRouter(props => <Nav {...props} />);
```

sugiero que entren a la pagina web y hagan scroll y abran menu y entren a una de las paginas para que puedan observar bien a lo que me refiero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es de la documentación oficial de `react-router` es un componente que sirve para cada vez que cambias de ruta

```
class ScrollToTop extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)
```

El componente `ScrollTop` debe ser hijo de `Router`, no puede estar por encima, luego puedes wrapear los componentes que te interesan, en el ejemplo está lo más arriba posible, pero podrías elegir los que quieres que lo utilicen y los que no

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router basename="/" hashType="noslash">
    <ScrollToTop>  
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/technologies" component={Technologies} />
        <Route path="/usecases" component={UseCases} />
        <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
        <Route path="/contactus" component={ContactUs} />
      </Switch>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```